# Dynamic object property name begins with number

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dynamic object whose property begins with number. How to access this property?

For inst:

```
myResult.123; // this is unvalid
```

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using ExpandoObject for your dynamic object, you can cast to `IDictionary<string, object>` and use an indexer;

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
var dict = (IDictonary<string, object>)expando;
dict["123"] = 2;
```

Many other dynamic object implementations (e. g. JObject in Json.NET) provide similar functionality.

Here's an example with JObject:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "123", 10 } });
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);

// using the IDictionary interface
var ten = ((IDictionary<string, JToken>)deserialized)["123"].Value<JValue>().Value;
Console.WriteLine(ten.GetType() + " " + ten); // System.Int64 10

// using dynamic
dynamic d = deserialized;
Console.WriteLine(d["123"].Value.GetType() + " " + d["123"].Value); // System.Int64 10
```

Comment: ı use 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' which comes with library. So I cannot change it to Dictionary<string, object>.

Comment: Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>'

Comment: @Mesult Cast to IDictionary, not Dictionary. In the case of JObject, it implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`. Check out http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: `JObject` is not `dynamic`. It is exactly `JObject`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: but you can assign JObject to a dynamic variable and use it dynamically, much like ExpandoObject.

Comment: If you get `JSON` which will be mapped to property with name starting with digit, then you get invalid `JSON`.

Comment: Code: 
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);
var r2 = (IDictionary<string, object>)results.data.category;

Error:

Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan, are you sure= I so, I cannot process my json document with json.net.

Comment: @Mesut: check out my updated answer. I've added a specific example with JObject

Answer (score 0):

Modified

```
Type t = myResult.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
{
   object value = GetPropValue(myResult, prp.Name);
   dict.Add(prp.Name, value);
}

public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
   return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But don't give expected values. Here are values:

Type
Item
Item
HasValues
First
Last
Count
Parent
Root
Next
Previous
Path

Comment: I modified my answer. Try modified solution.